# On win10, how to bind shortcut to context menu item?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

If I want to open a folder with a software, e.g. vs code, I have to first select the folder in the explorer, then right click and move to context menu, at last choose "open with vs code".

I was wondering if I can somehow bind a shortcut, e.g. Ctrl+Y, to "open with vs code", so that I only need to select the folder, then use the shortcut to open that folder with vs code.

Since copy(Ctrl+C), paste(Ctrl+V), cut(Ctrl+X), rename(F2), etc. in the context menu all have shortcuts, I believe this can be done for other items in context menu, too.

Do you have any idea? Vs code is used here as a example, I want to find a way to bind shortcut to any item in context menu.

Comment: The keyboard accelerator being underlined is only shown if the context menu was invoked by keyboard. So use the *Context* key (right hand side of keyboard near Alt) or Shift+F10, The accelerator works if shown or not. Same for menus. On my computer it is *Open With Code* and the `i` is underlined.

Comment: If you define VS Code as the handler for some file-types, it will be enough to double-click the file in order to open it in VS Code.

Comment: @harrymc open certain file types is easy, but I want to open a folder instead

Comment: @user1292580 Your tip would only work for system command, such as copy, past, cut.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Programs are supposed to add a accelerator key to their menu entries. In Windows everything must be able to be done with a keyboard for accessibility reasons.

Comment: @user1292580 So, it seems to me that only windows programs (copy,  paste, cut, rename) can have a shortcut, while other user programs can at most have an accelerator. Is it correct?

Comment: In the programming menus world the terms are reversed. SC keys means accelerators and vice versa.  I was being technically accurate while talking about menus. So what are you talking about. In user interface terms an underlined letter is an accelerator. It is specified in the menu definition. A key like Ctrl+C is a shortcut key. It is specified in the `Accel` structure - the table of shortcut keys. Both menus and shortcut keys point to a *CommandID*.

Comment: If a *CommandID* exists in both tables then the shortcut key will appear on the menu **and** if you press the shortcut key it checks with the menu if the menu item is enabled.

Comment: @user1292580 I got your points. So how can I bind shortcut to a specific item in context menu? Maybe through registry? Detailed instructions are appreciated.

Comment: Not without writing a context menu extension. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#programmaticaccessonly-verbs

Answer (score 0):

This same demand was made in the StackOverflow post
[How to open folder in new vs code instance by right clicking on the folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151953/how-to-open-folder-in-new-vs-code-instance-by-right-clicking-on-the-folder)

If you wish to open the folder from the VS Code Explorer,
you could use the extension
[Open Folder Context Menus for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrisdias.vscode-opennewinstance).

IF you wish to do it from the Windows Explorer, the following `.reg`
file was
[proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57889839/165358)
to add this option to the context menu:

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Change the folders in the above text to follow your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to add shortcut, not just add "open with vs code" into context menu. It seems to me the .reg above wouldn't add a shortcut. I will edit my question to make it clear. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You put an ampersand before the letter you want as an accelerator. It already has `i`.